# Display legend with two different colour palettes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I create the following plot in R:

```
library(ggplot2)
df_plot = data.frame(KL=runif(15,0,10),x=seq(0,1,length=15),y=seq(0,1,length=15))
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = subset(df_plot, KL > 1), aes(x=x, y=y, col=KL),
             color = c(heat.colors(sum(df_plot$KL>1))), size =3) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df_plot, KL < 1), aes(x=x, y=y, col = KL), size = 3)
```

which is [image]

My problem is on the legend. It has the range with the colors of only the points that are `<1` and it doesn't display the colors with the points above the `>1`.

is there a way to display the whole range of colors from `0`up to `10` with the range `[0,1]` corresponding to the blue palette and the `(1,10]` to the heat palette?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic, i.e. doing so you could pass your heat colors to e.g. `scale_color_gradientn` instead of setting via the `color` argument and hence get a legend:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(123)

df_plot <- data.frame(KL = runif(15, 0, 10), x = seq(0, 1, length = 15), y = seq(0, 1, length = 15))

pal_heat <- heat.colors(sum(df_plot$KL > 1))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = subset(df_plot, KL > 1), aes(x = x, y = y, col = KL), size = 3
  ) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colors = pal_heat) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(data = subset(df_plot, KL < 1), aes(x = x, y = y, col = KL), size = 3)
```

[image]